# Rails Doorkeeper - Redirect to homepage instead of authorize page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth

I have a weird problem when I try to use door_keeper gem with rails app. The problem occurs when I use Oauth2 gem to get the token. But at the part I have url :

`http://0.0.0.0:3000/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=199f27a02764f1ef1d31c2860b83ef93c0cc3dc26886d2b3d76b8ef1e935f3ae&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3000%2Fcallback`

it doesn't redirect to the page we authorize and get token but it redirects directly to `http://0.0.0.0:3000`

what's the problem I have here, it should redirect to application authorize page first, shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

The authorization page requires some user to be logged in. You set up that in the `resource_owner_authenticator` block and it should look something like this:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do |routes|
  # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
  # If you want to use named routes from your app you need
  # to call them on routes object eg.
  # routes.new_user_session_path
  User.find(session[:user_id]) || routes.new_user_session_path
end
```

In this case, if the user is not in the session when it tries to access `/oauth/authorize`, it gets redirected back to `new_user_session_path`.

Only when the user was found from the session, you'll be able to see the authorization page.

Comment: I get a `undefined local variable or method 'routes' for #<Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController:0x007fcf577d0900>` error.

Comment: resource_owner_authenticator do |routes|